# Can I set css grid row height based on if anything targets it with grid-area?

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible to set a css grid row height based on if the grid area is being used?

```css
.container {

  height: 100vh;

  grid-template-areas: 
    "mobile-head mobile-head mobile-head" 
    "nav app app"
    "footer footer footer";
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
   <div class="nav">Nav stuff</div>
 </div>
```

Given the above grid template and html, I see the Nav stuff in the nav area, but naturally the mobile nav area is taking a 1/3rd of the screen height.  Because there is no div that has a grid-area: mobile-head I want the height to be 0px.

But if I change the .nav to

```css
...
  .nav {
    grid-area: mobile-head 
}
```

I would want the row to be a fixed height of say 200px.

I can get close.  I can get the row to have a height of 0 when there is nothing in the mobile-area by doing this:

```css
  ...
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0px, auto) 1fr 1fr
```

But then the height is dictated by the content, rather than the grid.

I'm fairly sure the only alternative to achieve what im trying to do is to use 2 grids, and media queries.  (I want to place the nav on the left for desktop, or top if mobile)

Comment: There is no `mobile-nav` area defined in your grid-area declaration. Did you mean `mobile-head`?

Answer (score 0):

I think `grid-auto-rows: min-content` is what you're after.

```html
<button class="toggle" style="margin-bottom:1em">Toggle hidden row</button>
<div class="container">
   <div class="nav">Nav stuff</div>
</div>
<style>
.container {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px lightgray;
  background-color: #fafafb;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "mobile-head mobile-head mobile-head" 
    "nav app app"
    "footer footer footer";
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.nav.mobile {
  grid-area: mobile-head;
}
</style>
<script>
document.querySelector('.toggle').onclick = function(){
  document.querySelector('.nav').classList.toggle('mobile');
};
</script>
```